# Shortcut to get to the java stack trace console

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, shortcut

I'm a keyboard shortcut addict.
Eclipse has a nice feature which is the "Java stack trace console".
However I am not able to find a nice way to get there without using the mouse.

I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd> to get to the console view, but then I want to switch to the "Java stack trace console" (or to any other of the consoles)

In the "open console" dialog, all consoles have a number, so I assume that I'm only missing the hotkey to precede the number.

Comment: I hadn't seen this and I just posted the same question. Let's see if I get better luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324062/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-consoles

Comment: It did, in fact, got solved. Check out the answer to my question.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, this is different problem. There is two menus on Console View: Open Console and Show Selected Console. I think Nils Otto here asked for Open Console where you asked for Show Selected Console. Anyway, check the update of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running on the Windows platform.

Under Mac the default is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> that allows you to open any view.

Check. Preferences > General > Keys. The **"Next View"** shortcut will allow you to open any view.

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I know how to get to the console-view itself (either by cmd+f7 or directly with alt-shift-q c) My "problem" arises when I get to the console and want to switch between open consoles

Answer (score 1):

Check my Eclipse Accessibility Plugin: http://www.martialjava.com/2010/07/eclipse-plugin-open-console/

Hope you like it!