# Eclipse: Keyboard shortcut for switching between consoles?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse (I'm using version 3.6 aka Helios), you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (on Mac OS X or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> on Windows/Linux) to give focus to the Console View. Ok. That's good.

My problem is that in order to switch *between consoles* inside that view you have to click the ridiculously small arrow next to the 'Display Selected Console' icon. See:

[image]

I find that quite annoying because I'm totally keyboard oriented and that is practically the only thing for which I have to use the mouse when in Eclipse. I'm frequently launching several Run Configurations at once, and every one opens a new Console. It is annoying trying to click that little arrow in order to 1) See what consoles are open and 2) switching between them. =(

Is there any keyboard friendly way of switching between opened consoles within the Console View?

Answer (score 45):

I'm not sure when this feature was added, but at least in Indigo you can cycle through the consoles using the "Next Page" and "Previous Page" commands.  These are mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> by default.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't upgraded from Helios to Indigo, but it looks like this is the functionality I wanted. I will update the question as soon as I'm able to confirm this.

Comment: It's Ctrl-F7 for me (Eclipse 4.2 on Linux)

Comment: Atl+F7 works fine in Eclipse Luna on Win 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you could do this (will be happy to learn something new as always), but, I can offer a workaround.

You can open several console views: in the right most menu in the console select New Console View. Open as many as you need. Each should show a different console. Use the Pin Console button to make sure they don't switch on you.

Now, the problem is reduced to navigating open views with the keyboard. This can be achieved with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Not ideal, but might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks. This is a reasonable workaround, and it is good to at least have an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

In mac you can use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to switch between consoles. You would have to be in the console for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux;  feel free to use CTRL+F7