# rj error when running rj console in Eclipse using StatET plugin

Tags: eclipse, r, eclipse-plugin, statet

I'm new to R and I use Eclipse a lot so I decided to install the StatET plugin in eclipse.  Everything went smoothly except that I have [the same problem as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727822/how-does-one-install-rj-in-statet-plugin-for-eclipse)...

**Random true facts:**
Windows XP Version 5.1.2600
Eclipse 3.6
StatET 0.9.2

I tried to install rj-0.5.2-1 [from here](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet), which is the package recommended for StatET 0.9.2.  I put the tar.gz file in the same directory as R.exe and successfully installed it, here is the command line output...

```
H:\DATA\R\R-2.13.0\bin>R CMD INSTALL --no-test-load rj_*.tar.gz
* installing to library 'H:/DATA/R/R-2.13.0/library'
* installing *source* package 'rj' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'rj'
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
* DONE (rj)

H:\DATA\R\R-2.13.0\bin>
```

When it was done I could see the rj folder in the H:\DATA\R\R-2.13.0\library folder, so I thought it worked.  However when I start Eclipse and start the RJ console I still get this error message...

```
[INFO] The R package 'rj' is not available, R-StatET tools cannot be initialized.
```

I also tried installing the rj-0.5.5-3 package since the binaries are precompiled; however, that didn't work either.  I still get the same error message.

I noticed that at the bottom of the stackoverflow page I posted above that there is a post by Allan Stokes that states this error message is not true.  Is this correct?  How can I tell if this error message is a Eclipse/StatET bug or that my rj package is not installed properly?  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you also installed rJava?  Here is a useful guide and checklist for installation: http://flyordie.sin.khk.be/statet/   Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I installed rJava.  I am certain that rJava is functioning properly because when I first installed StatET I could not start a RJ console without getting a popup indicating that I needed rJava.  After I installed rJava the RJ console started with no popups.  The only problem I have now is the error message saying package 'rj' is not available.  I followed the link you posted, I have already done everything shown on that page.

Comment: I found that this message occurs when the rj package isn't found.  I ran the following command at the r command prompt...

'("rj" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])'

and the r command prompt returned a FALSE message.  However, my installation of rj did not indicate any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is allowed to answer your own question, but I managed to get it working and I thought I'd post my solution.  For some reason R was not recognizing the rj library when it was installed on my H: drive which is a portable drive, not my system drive.  I uninstalled R and reinstalled it on my C: drive, which is my system drive.  I installed rJava and rj just like before and in the r console I ran...

```
("rj" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])
```

it returned true indicating that the package was there, this command returned false when R was installed on my H: drive.  I went into Eclipse/StatET and setup my R environment with the new location of R and ran RJ and there was no error.  I'm not sure why this solution worked.  Maybe the rj package need to be installed in a very specific manner.  I don't understand why some libraries worked on the H: drive and some didn't.  The rJava package would work on the H: drive and that the rj package wouldn't.  Why is this?  Ah well, it's working now.  The info on this mailing list helped a lot...

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2011-March/000812.html