# How to index R library for Help view of StatEt Eclipse plugin?

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

When I show the view "R Help" of the StatEt Eclipse plugin I get following error:

```
 HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /rhelp/browse/default-workbench/. Reason: 
    The R library of the requested R environment <code>R</code> is not yet indexed. Please run the indexer first to enable R help support.


Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.7.v20170914
```

=> How do I index the R library to fix the help view?

I use Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) and R-3.4.3.

I am able to execute R in the Console with Launch type Rterm.

My Environment settings are:

[image]

My run configuration settings are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some doc i found helpful for the first steps:

http://epbi-radivot.cwru.edu/EPBI473/files/week1Rbasics/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf

http://www.walware.de/goto/statet

[How to disable "Save workspace image?" prompt in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r)

Related questions:

- [ClassNotFoundException for StatEt Eclipse plugin / RJ. Compatibility issue with Java9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096198/classnotfoundexception-for-statet-eclipse-plugin-rj-compatibility-issue-with)
- [How does one install 'rj' in StatET plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727822/how-does-one-install-rj-in-statet-plugin-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment Cedric I found following answer:

RJ needs to be used instead of Rterm (and RJ is not compatible to Java9)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the option "Default R environment" I entered a custom url for the help view: https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

[image]

Comment: I didn't experience a similar problem with the current stable version of statet, In Run configuration, edit your R configuration>  R console  there are a couple of options there are the box checked ?

Comment: The inline help of statet is very usefull, try to make it work.

Comment: The options are checked, see screenshots in updated question.

Comment: If you use Rterm it won't work. You need to install package rj. Have you managed to install it. What system are you running ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096198/classnotfoundexception-for-statet-eclipse-plugin-rj-compatibility-issue-with

Comment: If you write your comment that RJ needs to be used instead of Rterm (and that RJ is not compatible to Java9) as an answer I'll accept it.