# How to automatically start and close R Console for StatEt plugin?

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I want to use the Eclipse plugin StatEt to develop R code. In order to do so, I always have to start my R Console run configuration. Otherwise I get the error

```
No session of R is active in the current workbench window.
```

When I am finished and try to close Eclipse, I get a warning popup:

[image]

Extra starting and closing the console is annoying. I use this instance of Eclipse only for StatEt

=> **How can I auto-execute the run configuration on Eclipse startup** and

=> How can I **avoid the warning window when closing Eclipse**? (How to chose "Exit Workbench now and remember my decision"? or so)

What already helped a little was to use the Options/Arguments `--silent --no-save` in the R Console run configuration. Otherwise there would be another annoying warning when closing the console.

Here it is stated that there is an "Auto Run" plugin, which is listed under the "Utilities" category on the StatET update site:

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2009-March/000128.html

However, using http://download.walware.de/eclipse-4.6 I could not find such a plugin. Therefore I guess that that plugin was available for an older version of StatET?

Related questions:

- [How to use "R Graph Builder" and "R Graphics" view with StatEt Eclipse Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942864/how-to-use-r-graph-builder-and-r-graphics-view-with-statet-eclipse-plugin)
- [How to index R library for Help view of StatEt Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941228/how-to-index-r-library-for-help-view-of-statet-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: Hi, I've never asked myself the question, I often have many sessions running with different codes, so I just close them before closing eclipse. An yes upon opening eclipse, or returning to the windows, I launch an R console. Does organize favorite helps? then you just have a button to click on.

Comment: For that Eclipse Instance I currently only have one run configuration and clicking the run configuration button is enough. =>I already enjoy the benefit of "Organize Favorites..." Nevertheless I found it annoying. I first tried R Studio and I did not expect that I  need to start a run configuration before being able to use R with StatEt. Now I know at least that manually starting and closing the session is the default work flow and that I don't have wrong settings.