# In eclipse is there a way to run more than one Java app in different console windows?

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse is there a way to run more than one Java app in different console windows
and switch between them ?

Comment: Consider using my plugin to avoid hand fatigueness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324062/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-consoles/3333728#3333728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the Console view there is an icon (a blue monitor, the last-but-one on the row) that allows you to switch consoles.[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, it launches each app in different console. All you have to do is switch it manually between consoles.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kit.edu](http://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/mediawiki/images/6/66/Eclipse-switch-to-OCL-console.png))</sub>